# SoftLayer API Hardware : How to order Bare Metal Server without OS using REST API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

How to order bare metal server without OS using REST API.

SoftLayer_Product_Package/getAllObjects we will get the package details under this which package Id needs to be selected.
Package 200 is bare metal server which requires OS and also package 50 is bare metal instance which requires OS.
Inform me which package ID will support for without OS.

Answer (score 0):

The packages that would be ordered without OS (Operating System) are the following:

> - (50) Bare Metal Instance
> - (56) Quad Processor Multi Core Nehalem EX
> - (126) Single Xeon 1200 Series (Sandy Bridge / Haswell)
> - (142) Single Xeon 2000 Series (Sandy Bridge)
> - (143) Dual Xeon 2000 Series (Sandy Bridge)
> - (144) Specialty Server: GPU
> - (146) Sandy Bridge 1270
> - (147) Specialty Server: 4u Mass Storage Dual Xeon 2000 (Sandy Bridge)    Series
> - (148) Specialty Server: 2u Mass Storage Dual Xeon 2000 (Sandy Bridge)    Series
> - (158) Quad Xeon 4000 Series (Sandy Bridge)
> - (234) Quad Xeon E7-4800 v2 (Ivy Bridge) Series
> - (248) Dual E5-2600 v3 Series (36 Drives)
> - (251) Dual E5-2600 v3 Series (12 Drives)
> - (253) Dual E5-2600 v3 Series (4 Drives)
> - (255) Single E3-1270 (4 Drives)
> - (257) Single E3-1270 v3 (4 Drives)
> - (259) Single E5-2600 Series (4 Drives)
> - (261) Single E3-1270 (2 Drives)
> - (263) Dual E5-2600 Series (36 Drives)
> - (265) Dual E5-2600 Series (12 Drives)
> - (267) Quad E5-4600 Series (24 Drives)
> - (269) Quad E7-4800 Series (6 Drives)
> - (271) Quad E7-4800 v2 Series (24 Drives)
> - (273) Dual E5-2600 (4 Drives)
>
> Note: This is only a reference list. You need to consider that some of these package could be inactive for different reasons (availability, deprecated).

How can you get packages which not require an OS?

We need to get the item price which refers to "No Operating System". Doing some tests I found this item price "37120" which refers to "No Operating System". So, you can try the following rest request to get packages which contain this item price:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price/37120/getPackages

Method: Get
```

Once you chose a package, you can proceed to place an order, here a Rest request example:

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder

Method: Post

{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "location":"448994",
         "packageId":261,
         "hardware":[  
            {  
               "hostname":"rcvtest1",
               "domain":"softlayer.com"
            }
         ],
         "prices":[  
            {  
               "id":"50461"
            },
            {  
               "id":"50377"
            },
            {  
               "id":"37120"
            },
            {  
               "id":"876"
            },
            {  
               "id":"50041"
            },
            {  
               "id":"50357"
            },
            {  
               "id":"273"
            },
            {  
               "id":"55"
            },
            {  
               "id":"58"
            },
            {  
               "id":"420"
            },
            {  
               "id":"418"
            },
            {  
               "id":"21"
            },
            {  
               "id":"57"
            },
            {  
               "id":"906"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

To get information about the item prices for a package, you can use the following rest request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/261/getItemPrices

Method: Get
```

References:

- [SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price::getPackages](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price/getPackages)
- [SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItemPrices](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices)
- [SoftLayer_Product_Order::placeOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder)

Comment: SoftLayer_Product_Package_Server/getAllObjects we will get BARE_METAL_CORE,BARE_METAL_CPUT,etc., under that we can select the package ID. For example : 248 and 253. After that invoke SoftLayer_Product_Package/253/getItemPrices in the response we will get keyName": "OS_NO_OPERATING_SYSTEM" So it confirmed that this package (253) is of  No Operating System.  But if we invoke configuration details : SoftLayer_Product_Package/253/getConfiguration in the response we are getting OS is mandatory. 
 "A server option is required to order a server"
"isRequired": 1
"itemCategoryId": 1
"packageId": 253

Comment: You are right. It can be confused but the package needs an Operating System "itemCategory" in its configuration, and according getItemPrices method, the item price: 37120 (No Operating System) is considered as itemCategory "Operating System", it means that SoftLayer is managing the "No Operating System" option as an item price.