# SoftLayer REST API for Bare Metals

Tags: api, rest, autoscaling, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We are using SoftLayer Rest API for creating/modifying/deleting autoscale groups. Can we also use SoftLayer REST API, or any other kinds of APIs, to create/modify/delete bare metals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Create Bare Metal**

To create a baremetal using the simplified way, you need to use: [SoftLayer_Hardware_Server::createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/createObject) method.

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/createObject

Method: Post

{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "hostname":"rcvtest1",
         "domain":"softlayer.com",
         "processorCoreAmount":2,
         "memoryCapacity":2,
         "hourlyBillingFlag":true,
         "datacenter":{  
            "name":"dal05"
         },
         "operatingSystemReferenceCode":"UBUNTU_LATEST"
      }
   ]
}
```

There is another way to create a bare metal using [SoftLayer_Product_Order::placeOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder) method which provides more options at the moment to place an order, see the following forum to get more information about it:

[SoftLayer API Hardware : How to order Bare Metal Server without OS using REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366692/softlayer-api-hardware-how-to-order-bare-metal-server-without-os-using-rest-ap/35370174#35370174)

Another example:
https://softlayer.github.io/rest/place_order/

**2. Modify Bare Metal**

To modify a bare metal, you need to use [SoftLayer_Hardware_Server::editObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/editObject) method, here an example:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/$hardwareId/editObject

Method: Post
{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
       "hostname": "rctestpar2"

      }
   ]
}
```

You can edit some properties from your server, if you want to upgrade you should use: SoftLayer_Product_Order::placeOrder method, here an example in python:

https://softlayer.github.io/python/upgrade_examples/

**3. Delete Bare Metal**

To delete a bare metal, the following method will help with it: [SoftLayer_Hardware_Server::deleteObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/deleteObject):

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/155392/deteleObject

Method: Get
```

**Some references:**

- [Ordering Bare Metal Servers Using the SoftLayer
  API](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/ordering-bare-metal-servers-using-softlayer-api)
- [Rest](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/rest)

Comment: Thanks. This is useful.